# select count inside select dinstinct

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `attendance` which has columns `roll`, `class_id`, `status` and `att_date`.
I have another table named `class` which has columns `class_id` and `name`.
 I want to select distinct `class_id` and count `number` of `roll` which has `status = 1` where `date="some_date"` and then connect it to class table using `inner join.` and again apply where branch ="Computer science"

But I'm facing some problem.
This is an example of my table attendance:

```
roll | class_id | status | att_date
abc  |    1     |   0    | 19-06-2016
cvb  |    2     |   1    | 19-06-2016
nbs  |    1     |   1    | 19-06-2016
lkl  |    3     |   1    | 19-06-2016
ewq  |    3     |   1    | 19-06-2016
dff  |    2     |   1    | 19-06-2016
xyz  |    2     |   1    | 19-06-2016
```

This is an example of my table class:

```
id  |  name | branch
1   |  CS4  | Computer Science
2   |  CS5  | Computer Science
3   |  CS6  | Mechanical
```

and I want something like this :

```
total number of roll with status 1 | class_id  | name
1                                  |    1      | CS4
3                                  |    2      | CS5
2                                  |    3      | CS6
```

Can someone explain me ?
How can I approach with the query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `group by` within a `group by`:

```
select cnt, count(*) as num_status_1,
       group_concat(a.class_id order by a.class_id) as class_ids,
       group_concat(c.name order by a.class_id) as class_names
from (select class_id, count(*) as cnt 
      from attendance
      where status = 1
      group by class_id
     ) a join
     class c
     on a.class_id = c.class_id
group by cnt;
```

EDIT:

Note:  This aggregates by `cnt`, and you might not want to do that (your results are ambiguous).  This might be sufficient:

```
select cnt,
       a.class_id, c.nameclass_names
from (select class_id, count(*) as cnt 
      from attendance
      where status = 1
      group by class_id
     ) a join
     class c
     on a.class_id = c.id;
```

Or even:

```
select c.*,
       (select count(*) from attendance a where a.status = 1 and a.class_id = c.id)
from class c;
```

Comment: Hey @Gordon I need one more help. Consider if there is 2 or more entry of same roll twice for a day(att_date column), your query will count them too. How can I add distinct att_date in this query ?

Comment: @TomCruise . . . Either you would use a subquery for `attendance` or you should ask another question with suitable sample data and desired results.

Comment: Can you show e the example of subquery for attendance ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a more simpler way to do the job:

```
select a.class_id, b.name, count(a.*) as tot_status_1 
    from attendance a, class b 
    where a.class_id=b.id and a.status=1
```